# C++ operator() parenthesis - operator Type() vs Type operator()

Tags: c++

What's the difference if any?

For example: `int operator()` vs `operator int()`

I'm looking for an answer with "official" C++ documentation.

Comment: They are doing completely different things.

Comment: `int operator()` is a function call operator declaration missing a set of parenthesis while `operator int()` would be a conversion operator declaration.

Comment: Does your last statement mean you *know* the answer, but want to know that relevant parts of the language standard regardless ? Function call operators are covered in [over.call], § 13.5.4, while conversion operators are covered in [class.conv], § 12.3 of the standard.

Comment: I am not sure that this question should be closed: it is pretty specific and asks for only one aspect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first (`int operator()(...)`) is a *function call operator*, which turns an object into a *function object* that can be called like a function. This specific operator returns an `int`, the argument part is missing.

Example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int operator()(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

...

Foo foo;
int i = foo(1, 2);  // Call the object as a function, and it returns 3 (1+2)
```

---

The other (`operator int()`) is a *conversion operator*. This specific one allows an object to be implicitly (or explicitly if declared `explicit`) converted to an `int`. It *must* return an `int` (or whatever type is used, user-defined types like classes or structures can be used as well).

Example:

```
struct Bar
{
    operator int()
    {
        return 123;
    }
};

...

Bar bar;
int i = bar;  // Calls the conversion operator, which returns 123
```

The conversion operator is the opposite of a one-argument constructor.

Answer (score 3):

There's a huge difference.

`T operator()` is a call operator, so you could 'call' your class like this:

```
class stuff {
    // init etc
    int operator()() {
        return 5;
    }
};

auto A = stuff(); // init that
cout << A() << endl; // call the object
```

`operator T()` is for converting an object of your class to type `T`, so you could do this:

```
class stuff {
    operator int() {
        return 5;
    }
};

auto A = stuff();
cout << int(A) << endl;
```

The conversion could be strictly `explicit` and explicit or implicit, like the one above.